# MVC4 Razor : HTTPPost and Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, http-post

I'm trying to send via httppost a model that contains a dictionnary but that disctionnary is always null... 
Here is my model :

```
public class RoomListModel
    {
        public Dictionary<PersonModel, List<LocationModel>> list { get; set; }
        public String mess { get; set; }
        public RoomListModel(Dictionary<PersonModel, List<LocationModel>> list, String mess)
        {
            this.mess = mess;
            this.list = list;
        }

        public RoomListModel()
        {
        }
    }
```

In a first view, that kind of model is correctly filled and displayed (i've done some tests). Then I try to send it filled from a view to my controller. Here is my view :

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.list.Count(); i++) {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Key.isSelected)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Key.login)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Key.login)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Key.role)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Key.role)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @for (int j = 0; j < Model.list.ElementAt(i).Value.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Value.ElementAt(j).isSelected )
                            @Html.DisplayFor( m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Value.ElementAt(j).id )
                            @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Value.ElementAt(j).id )
                            @Html.HiddenFor( m => m.list.ElementAt(i).Value.ElementAt(j).name)<br />
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

But when that form is send, i've got a nullReferenceException :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateInventory(RoomListModel mod)
        {
            int nbPer = 0;
            foreach (var per in mod.list)
            {
                if (per.Key.isSelected)
                {
                    nbPer++;
                }
            }
            if (nbPer == 0)
            { ...
```

On mod.list.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code ? Is it because of the Dictionnary object ? Thanks !

Comment: What exactly is null? RoomListModel mod?

Comment: Yes, that's at line "foreach (var per in mod.list)"

Comment: So your dictionary 'list' is empty.

Comment: I do agree with that. My question is Why, and how to fill it ?